# Access Slim Framework Flash on the same file

Tags: php, slim

Hello so I have a simple code here:

```
index.php
function AddUser() {
//database codes
$newUserLastID = $db->lastInsertId();
$app->flash('test', $newUserLastID);
}
AddUser();
```

What I wanted to do is access the flash `test` to the same file and assign it to a variable. The code I made is:

```
$someVar = $flash['test'];
```

And I always get an `undefined variable $flash` error. Can you access the flash message within the same php file?

Comment: What is the value of `$flash` or what is its origin?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `flashNow`

```
$app->flashNow('info', 'Your credit card is expired');
```

see [Slim Documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/flash/now/)

> The Slim application’s `flashNow()` method sets a message that will be available in the current request’s view templates. Messages set with the `flashNow()` application instance method will not be available in the next request. The message in the example below will be available in the template variable `flash['info']`.

Comment: This is how you set a flash.

Comment: @FewFlyBy You've used ``flash``, but not ``flashNow``, ``flash`` is available in the next request, ``flashNow`` is in the current request, so what does you'r comment mean?